# Regular Expression to remove vendor prefixed CSS

Tags: regex

Seems pretty simple, but with RegEx it seems nothing is simple. All I want to do is take an array of CSS properties like this:

```
[ 'background',
  'border',
  'font-size',
  'margin',
  'outline',
  'padding',
  'vertical-align',
  'line-height',
  'display',
  'list-style',
  'quotes',
  'content',
  'background-color',
  'color',
  'text-decoration',
  'font-style',
  'font-weight',
  'border-bottom',
  'cursor',
  'border-collapse',
  'border-spacing',
  'border-top',
  'height',
  'box-shadow',
  'text-shadow',
  'page-break-inside',
  'max-width',
  'orphans',
  'widows',
  'page-break-after',
  'font-family',
  'src',
  'speak',
  'font-variant',
  'text-transform',
  'text-rendering',
  '-webkit-font-smoothing',
  '-moz-osx-font-smoothing',
  'box-sizing',
  'width',
  '-webkit-tap-highlight-color',
  'margin-top',
  'margin-bottom',
  'margin-left',
  'touch-action',
  'padding-top',
  'padding-bottom',
  'text-align',
  'caption-side',
  'border-radius',
  'resize',
  'min-width',
  '-webkit-appearance',
  'clear',
  'margin-right',
  'foat',
  'float',
  'position',
  'overflow',
  'clip',
  'visibility',
  'font',
  'text-overflow',
  'white-space',
  'padding-left',
  'padding-right',
  '-ms-word-break',
  'word-break',
  '-webkit-hyphens',
  '-moz-hyphens',
  '-ms-hyphens',
  'hyphens',
  'pading-left',
  'border-left',
  'border-right',
  'top',
  'left',
  'transform',
  '-webkit-transform',
  'z-index',
  'right',
  'bottom',
  'max-height',
  'isplay',
  'overflow-x',
  'flex-wrap',
  'min-height',
  'flex',
  'order',
  'align-items',
  'align-self',
  'background-image',
  'opacity',
  'background-size',
  'background-repeat',
  'data',
  'user-select',
  'border-color',
  'transition',
  'pointer-events',
  'boder-color',
  'border-top-right-radius',
  'border-bottom-right-radius',
  'border-top-left-radius',
  'border-bottom-left-radius',
  'border-width',
  'border-style',
  '-ms-transform' ]
```

And remove all of the vendor prefixed ones. What would the regular expression look like to only match strings like this `-ms-transform` and not strings like this `border-width`?

Comment: This is all I've been able to come up with `/(-[a-z-]+)/`. If I had something that came remotely close to working I would have put it. @Tushar

Comment: Okay, add that in question. Always show your efforts when asking questin.

Comment: @mascaliente: Be careful while using `-` in character class. It denotes range. You might wanna escape it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [`RegExp#test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).

```
var regex = /^-(webkit|moz|ms|o)-/;
var nonVendorPrefixedProperties = arr.filter(prop => !regex.test(prop));
```

The [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix)

1. `-webkit-`: Chrome, newer versions of Opera
2. `-moz-`: Firefox
3. `-o-`: Old versions of Opera
4. `-ms-`: Internet Explorer

**RegEx Explanation:**

1. `^`: Start of line
2. `-`: Match hyphen
3. `(webkit|moz|ms|o)`: Match vendor prefix `webkit`, `moz`, `ms` or `o`.

```js
var arr = ['background',
    'border',
    'font-size',
    'margin',
    'outline',
    'padding',
    'vertical-align',
    'line-height',
    'display',
    'list-style',
    'quotes',
    'content',
    'background-color',
    'color',
    'text-decoration',
    'font-style',
    'font-weight',
    'border-bottom',
    'cursor',
    'border-collapse',
    'border-spacing',
    'border-top',
    'height',
    'box-shadow',
    'text-shadow',
    'page-break-inside',
    'max-width',
    'orphans',
    'widows',
    'page-break-after',
    'font-family',
    'src',
    'speak',
    'font-variant',
    'text-transform',
    'text-rendering',
    '-webkit-font-smoothing',
    '-moz-osx-font-smoothing',
    'box-sizing',
    'width',
    '-webkit-tap-highlight-color',
    'margin-top',
    'margin-bottom',
    'margin-left',
    'touch-action',
    'padding-top',
    'padding-bottom',
    'text-align',
    'caption-side',
    'border-radius',
    'resize',
    'min-width',
    '-webkit-appearance',
    'clear',
    'margin-right',
    'foat',
    'float',
    'position',
    'overflow',
    'clip',
    'visibility',
    'font',
    'text-overflow',
    'white-space',
    'padding-left',
    'padding-right',
    '-ms-word-break',
    'word-break',
    '-webkit-hyphens',
    '-moz-hyphens',
    '-ms-hyphens',
    'hyphens',
    'pading-left',
    'border-left',
    'border-right',
    'top',
    'left',
    'transform',
    '-webkit-transform',
    'z-index',
    'right',
    'bottom',
    'max-height',
    'isplay',
    'overflow-x',
    'flex-wrap',
    'min-height',
    'flex',
    'order',
    'align-items',
    'align-self',
    'background-image',
    'opacity',
    'background-size',
    'background-repeat',
    'data',
    'user-select',
    'border-color',
    'transition',
    'pointer-events',
    'boder-color',
    'border-top-right-radius',
    'border-bottom-right-radius',
    'border-top-left-radius',
    'border-bottom-left-radius',
    'border-width',
    'border-style',
    '-ms-transform'
];

var regex = /^-(webkit|moz|ms)-/;
var nonVendorPrefixedProperties = arr.filter(prop => !regex.test(prop));

console.log(nonVendorPrefixedProperties);
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(nonVendorPrefixedProperties, 0, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: Good ..! Really I cannot understand what is difference between `^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z-]+` and `^[a-zA-Z]+` ..! I can see their different in the output, but I can understand the mean of those regex ..